# Subquery returned more than 1 value when trigger executes

Tags: sql-server

I have a trigger which adds a log entry into a table upon a field change in another table.  it works when one row is changed but errors when multiple rows re changed.  Anyone out there able to explain what I have to do to get my trigger working also for multi row updates?

Many thanks,

Derek

```
Declare @PropertyID uniqueidentifier

    Set @PropertyID = (Select CONVERT(VARCHAR( 36 ), ISNULL(i.[PropertyPK], d.[PropertyPK]))
    FROM 
        INSERTED i 
    FULL OUTER JOIN DELETED d ON ( d.[PropertyPK] = i.[PropertyPK] )

    WHERE 
        ( d.[strManagingOfficeName] <> i.[strManagingOfficeName] ) OR
        ( d.[strManagingOfficeName] IS NULL AND i.[strManagingOfficeName] IS NOT NULL ) OR
        ( i.[strManagingOfficeName] IS NULL AND d.[strManagingOfficeName] IS NOT NULL ))

    Declare @CompanyID uniqueidentifier

    Set @CompanyID = (Select CompanyFK From Property Where PropertyPK = @PropertyID)

    --Deleted Old Ones

    Delete From TDSAPILog Where ObjectFK = @PropertyID And strObject = 'Branch Change'

    --Insert New Log

    INSERT dbo.TDSAPILog(TDSAPILogPK, ObjectFK, strObject, strStatus, CompanyFK, dteDateLogged)
    SELECT
        NewID(),
        @PropertyID,
        'Branch Change',
        'Active',
        @CompanyID ,
        GetDate()
```

Comment: The virtual tables `inserted` and `deleted` contain **all** the rows you're updating, so you can't fetch the values into a single variable.

Comment: Your trigger is broken. It assumes there will only ever be a single row in inserted. In sql server triggers fire once per operation. To handle this your triggers need to be set based.

Comment: Ah..  So my @PropertyID = is the issue, plus adding to my log at the end will have to cope with multiple values..  Thank you..

Comment: Yes Sean, silly assumption..  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occur when you return more than 1 value from a query and save in a variable or compare with a value in where clause.

In your example I think the error occur at this line

```
SET @CompanyID = (SELECT CompanyFK FROM Property WHERE PropertyPK = @PropertyID)
```

To resolve the reported error just put "TOP 1" in your query. Example is shown here:

```
SET @CompanyID = (SELECT TOP 1 CompanyFK FROM Property WHERE PropertyPK = @PropertyID)
```

Subquery returned more than 1 value error may occur at the following scenarios:

```
SET @YouVariable = (SELECT ColumnID FROM yourTable WHERE Identity = @SomeValue)

-- if the above query return more than 1 value the same error will be occurred
-- to resolve this problem just put "TOP 1" before ColumnID  

SELECT * 
FROM OtherTable 
WHERE OtherIdentity = ((SELECT ColumnID FROM yourTable 
                        WHERE Identity = @SomeValue))

-- if the above query return more than 1 value the same error will be occurred
-- to resolve this problem just replace "= with IN()". Example give below
SELECT * 
FROM OtherTable 
WHERE OtherIdentity IN ((SELECT ColumnID FROM yourTable 
                         WHERE Identity = @SomeValue))
```

Comment: Hi Faraz..  Will it not error before that setting the @PropertyID = ?

Comment: This just hides the actual error. The real reason is that the trigger is broken because it always assumes a single record will be affected. Scalar variables don't cut it for this kind of situations, instead, use set-based operations in the trigger too.

Comment: Derek Jee Set CompanyID can store only a single value. if you want to store multiple records you have to declate a temp variable like Declare CompanyIDs table(CompanyID int)

Comment: Hi Alejandro, thank you.  Another comment above mentioned the same.  Strangely enough the CompanyFK is unique to the dababase so will be ok but the PropertyID is the issue where there could be multiple valuses..  Thanks for the comment..  :)